# How does (A == B == C) comparison work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, comparison, truthiness

I was expecting the following comparison to give an error:

```
var A = B = 0;
if(A == B == 0)
    console.log(true);
else
    console.log(false);
```

but strangely it returns `false`.

Even more strangely,

```
console.log((A == B == 1));
```

returns `true`.

How does this "ternary" kind of comparison work?

Comment: A == B is true and true is not 0

Comment: You can't compare like that, `if (A==0 && B==0)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, we need to understand that a `==` comparison between a number and a boolean value will result in internal type conversion of Boolean value to a number (`true` becomes `1` and `false` becomes `0`)

The expression you have shown is evaluated from left to right. So, first

```
A == B
```

is evaluated and the result is `true` and you are comparing `true` with 0. Since `true` becomes `1` during comparison, `1 == 0` evaluates to `false`. But when you say

```
console.log((A == B == 1));
```

`A == B` is `true`, which when compared with number, becomes `1` and you are comparing that with 1 again. That is why it prints `true`.

Answer (score 8):

Assignment operators like = are **right-associative**: when there is a series of these operators that have the same precedence, they are processed right-to-left, so `A = B = 0` is processed as `A = (B = 0)` (`B = 0` returns 0, so both A and B end up as 0).

Equality operators like == are **left-associative**: same-precedence operators are processed left-to-right. `A == B == 0` is processed as `(A == B) == 0`, and since `A == B` is true (1), it becomes `1 == 0`, which is false (0).

Likewise, `A == B == 1` is processed as `(A == B) == 1`, which becomes `1 == 1`, which is true (1).

Source and more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 2):

First, `A == B` returns `true`, which is then compared to 0, `true == 0` which returns false, or `true == 1` which returns true.

Answer (score 2):

It first checks your clause for A == B, which is true, than it starts checking true == 0, and 0 is false. So when you check A == B == 1, you check A==B, which is true, and true == 1. So then it returns true. If you really want to check all possibilities you should do something like this:

```
if((A==B) && (A==0))
   console.log(true);
else 
   console.log(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if((A == B)&& (A== 0)&& (B==0))
    console.log(true);
else
    console.log(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work from left to right. In this case you first check if A == B, then you check if this equal to 0. So since A == B, this is true. So now it becomes (true == 0), which is false. If A=1, B=2, then (A == B == 0) would return true! This is because A == B is false and (false == 0) is true!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should just need 2 comparisons here, but they do need to be independent. So just check:

```
(A==B && B=0) ? {if true this happens} : {if False this happens}
```

This should work the same as a triple comparison, unless you have 3rd condition in case `B === 0 and A !== 0` being different from `A ===0 and B !==0`, eliminating the need for comparing A and 0.