# Why does 1==1==1 return true, "1"=="1"=="1" return true, and "a"=="a"=="a" return false?

Tags: javascript

```
function a() { return (1 == 1 == 1); }
function b() { return ("1" == "1" == "1"); }
function c() { return ("a" == "a" == "a"); }
```

I tested the above code in Chrome's console and for some reason, `a()` returns true, `b()` returns true, and `c()` returns false.

Why is this so?

Comment: Hint: X == Y == Z is evaluated as ((X == Y) == Z).

Comment: Strangely, `true == "1"` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Related: [Why does (0 < 5 < 3) return true?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4089284/218196)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) and [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript).

Comment: @Cupcake question is different from you referring.

Comment: @Cupcake: In good faith, I think the main headscratcher here is that an equality that appears to be true mathematically is actually false as far as JS is concerned, not that e.g. `true == 1` is true. In other words, the aha moment is not realizing that the types play a part but rather that all of these are comparing something to `true`. I 'm sure there's a dupe of this somewhere, but IMO it's not one of those you offer.

Comment: @Jon ok, that's a fair argument. You've spent more time in this tag than I have, so I'll defer to you.

Comment: @Blackhole You just _sucked_ the first thought I had upon seeing this in the "hot" questions.

Comment: Javascript's definition of true and false is wicked blackmagic.

Comment: Here are a few more dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980471/how-does-a-b-c-comparison-work-in-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955573/why-is-1-1-1-false, this time with the == and === operator

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Because you are comparing the (boolean) result of the first equality with the (non-boolean) third value.

In code, `1 == 1 == 1` is equivalent to `(1 == 1) == 1` is equivalent to `true == 1`.

This means the three methods can be written more simply as:

```
function a() { return (true == 1); }
function b() { return (true == "1"); }
function c() { return (true == "a"); }
```

These comparisons work according to [these rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) (emphasis mine):

> **If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the
>   operands, then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a
>   number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if
>   possible**; else if either operand is a string, the string operand is
>   converted to a number if possible. If both operands are objects, then
>   JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands
>   refer to the same object in memory.

So what happens in `c` is that `"a"` is converted to a number (giving [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)) and the result is [strictly compared](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) to `true` converted to a number (giving `1`).

Since `1 === NaN` is `false`, the third function returns `false`. It's very easy to see why the first two functions will return `true`.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that using strict equal (`===`) operator will prevent this unexpected behaviour for `"1"`

Comment: @KonradGadzina: Strict equals will make all three functions return `false`.

Comment: You're right. I've seen so many `true` in here that I forgot about that. ^^

Comment: @Jon: `So what happens in c is that "a" is converted to a number (giving NaN)` neither operand is a number. I think the conversion ends up with `"true" == "a"` rather than `1 == NaN`.

Comment: @Flater I disagree. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#Python.2C_Ruby.2C_and_JavaScript

Comment: @Flater: No. The passage I have quoted above is very clear on what exactly happens ("if either operand is a number *or a boolean*" -- the left hand side operand *is* boolean). It's also very easy to see that your assertion is wrong: `1 == 1 == "true"` => `false`.

Answer (score 26):

Because `1 == true`

But `"a" != true`

So basically what happens is that

`1 == 1`, `"1" == "1"` and `"a" == "a"` are all evaluated to be `true` and then compared to the next value.

The string `"1"` is converted to a number (`1`) prior to being compared to `true` and is thus also considered to be equal to `true`.

Now, the "WHY?!?!" question is explained by the fact that Javascript has its roots in the C-family of languages. In which any number, other than 0 is considered to be a valid `true` boolean. :-/

Comment: JavaScript for sure does **not** have *its roots in the C-family of languages*. It has its roots in LISP dialects such as Scheme, and was inspired by Self as well. It only uses the syntax of C, but not its semantics. IMHO this is one of the most widespread and quite wrong misunderstandings of JavaScript. To underline this, please also have a look at Douglas Crockford's article [JavaScript: The World's Most Misunderstood Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/javascript.html).

Comment: @GoloRoden: Don't be silly.  If JavaScript didn't have C's semantics, a number of classic C semantical bugs such as `if (x = 5)` would not exist in JS... but they do, exactly as in C.  IT certainly doesn't have *all of* C's semantics, but it behaves a lot more like C than like any Lisp.

Comment: @MasonWheeler assignments in conditions is NOT a bug or defect.

Comment: @MilesRoul: Try telling that to... well... *everyone who's ever been bitten by it.*

Comment: @Masonwheeler is this really that common amongst anyone other than complete newbies? I've never ever done that by accident in 15 years.

Comment: @funkybro Being a pro doesn't mean accidents can't happen. I have been programming C for over 10 years and lately I found myself forgetting the `break;` in a C `switch` statement...

Comment: MasonWheeler: you're confusing "having roots" with "including poor design to appease the masses".  The history of JavaScript is well documented.

Comment: @nomen So true, but hey, "Don't be silly" ... ;-))

Answer (score 6):

Because 1 and "1" are both converted to true, as numbers.  This is not the case with "a".  Therefore:

```
("1" == "1" == "1")
```

evaluates to

```
(("1" == "1") == "1")
```

which evaluates to

```
(true == "1")
```

Similarly,

```
("1" == 1 == "1")
```

is also true, or any combination thereof.  In fact, any non-zero number when converted to a boolean is true.

Whereas, "a" does not evaluate to true.

Answer (score 5):

It's because JavaScript is a weakly typed language.  This means that it is not expressive enough to talk about types, and in fact implicitly coerces values to belong in types to which they have no semantic relation.  So, (1 == 1) == 1 evaluates to true because (1 == 1) correctly evaluates to true, so that JavaScript evaluates (true) = 1.  In particular, it is turning 1 to a boolean (or true to a number -- I forget which, but the result is effectively the same).

The point is that JavaScript is **turning** one type of value into another type of value behind your back.

Your question shows why this is a problem:  ('a' == 'a') == 'a' is false, because ('a' == 'a') is true, and JavaScript ends up comparing (true) == 'a'.  Since there is just **no** sensible way to turn a Boolean into a letter (or a letter into a boolean), that statement is false.  Of course, that breaks referential transparency for (==).

Answer (score 2):

It's true that `(1 == 1) == 1`. Then it will be `true == 1`, but not in `a == a == a`.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean handled as bits, each bit stands for true or false ( 1 for true, 0 for false )

so that 1 stands for true, and 0 stand for false

and 1 == 1 == 1 will be like (1 == 1) == 1, true == 1, true

while 'a' == 'a' == 'a' will be ('a' == 'a') == 'a', true == 'a', false

BONUS: 0 == 1 == 0, 1 == 0 == 0 and 0 == 0 == 1 returns true